# Array.Find Lambda expression Null

Tags: vb.net, lambda, windows-server-2012-r2

I have this statement in code:

```
idObj = Array.Find(Me.IdObjArray, Function(s) s.IdText = objText)
```

It should just return the object from the array where the IdText property matches the objText value.

It works great locally, it works great on production machines, but on a machine that is the same build as the prod machines used for testing it returns Null for some reason when there is a match. These are Server 2012 r2 virtual machines.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be, or what I could do to remedy this problem with out starting from a fresh image? The other option of course is to loop through the array, but I like the lambda method, as it is more elegant and this bothers me that it does not work on this one server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally figured out the issue, well kind of. When deploying to production we usually overwrite existing files. Once I deleted the bin and redeployed it started working. Not sure how that is possible, but oh well.